# Django cant find CSS for the admin page

Tags: django, django-admin

this just started today
I tried to reset css

```
[27/Oct/2020 22:56:44] "GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[27/Oct/2020 22:56:44] "GET /static/admin/css/responsive.css HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[27/Oct/2020 22:56:44] "GET /static/admin/css/nav_sidebar.css HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[27/Oct/2020 22:56:44] "GET /static/admin/js/nav_sidebar.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[27/Oct/2020 22:56:44] "GET /static/admin/css/dashboard.css HTTP/1.1" 404 179
```

Comment: double check if the actual files exist in the their directories, and also the spelling

Comment: I suggest to review the [static files docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/).  Please also read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Setting `DEBUG = True` in the settings.py worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it all I had to do was reset the database lol

Answer (score -1):

Are the files there? Do they have the right access rights? Is the apache configured well for /static/ (I suppose you use apache)